# Can I configure an app's notification preferences relative to the focus mode?

Tags: notifications, ventura, focus

e.g. I would like a 'call' focus that has Slack previews hidden, but in 'work' focus I want the Slack previews to not be hidden.

That is to say, I want Slack notifications in both focus modes, but I want notification-banner previews in one of the modes, and I do not want it to preview the notification-banners in the other mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I re-read the answer (edited) as well as your [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448868/can-i-configure-an-apps-notification-preferences-relative-to-the-focus-mode#comment674817_460175), I noticed that you weren't looking for a way to enable/disable notifications directly but instead for a way to set whether there is a preview of the notification.

I've gone over the possible parameters but there doesn't seem to be anything like what you're looking for.

If I were you, I would consider proposing this as a feature for a later update : [Apple Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

---

***I'm still leaving the previous answer here for other users to see as it might be helpful - though it is only context, and not a solution***

##### On iPhone and iPad

Go to *Settings > Focus > [name of your focus] > Apps*.

[image]

From there, add/remove the apps you want to allow/silence the notifications from (here Drive, Mail and Reminders are allowed to deliver notifications).

[image]

For more information and guidance on this, see [Use Focus on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT212608) and [Set up a Focus on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/set-up-a-focus-iphd6288a67f/ios).

##### On Mac

On Mac, the way to proceed is about the same as for iPhone and iPad.

You have to go to *System Settings > Focus > [name pf your focus] > Allowed apps*. From there, the steps to follow are the same as for iPhone and iPad.

For more information and guidance on this, see [Set up a Focus on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl613dc43f).

---

You can have two different focuses (from your example); one called 'Call', which will allow notifications from the Slack app, and one called 'Work', which will silence notifications from the Slack app.